# PS4 + Linux + POL + space engineers?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, ps4

A friend recently purchased space engineers for me. I quickly discovered my PC could not handle it on windows, much less POL. Because of my old CPU socket and the fact my CPU would clench my GPU if I upgraded it enough to run the game, i'd have to pretty much build another PC in order to run this game. However, I have seen around the internet people have found ways to install linux on the PS4. I don't understand how drivers would work, but of course the community has found ways. My questions are:

1: Would this run like a normal computer

2: Could I run space engineers on it via POL

(if not)

3: Can I install windows and run it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1. Would this run like a normal computer*

It is possible to run linux on it, but as it is now, it depends on a quite old firmware on the PS4 and many parts of the system won't work properly.

*2. Could I run space engineers on it via POL*

Sadly POL doesn't support Space Engineers. The system requirements for space engineers are quiet high. If you would like to run it on linux in wine you might need an even more powerful computer and I think the PS4 is not capable of that much power.

*3. Can I install windows and run it there*

There is no way of installing Windows on a PS4. The bootloader of the PS4 is blocking it and through the custom hardware of the PS4 Windows doesn't have the driver to run.

I think that the only way to run your game is to buy a new computer...